Engine sputtering when turning left
I have a 1988 Jeep Cherokee, and recently I’ve had this issue where whenever I turn left, the engine will sputter and sometimes go to nearly 0 rpm. I heard it could be an exhaust issue or a carburetor issue, but I’m not sure because I had my exhaust replaced a month and an half ago. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to the site! This question has been asked and answered before, see the duplicate link.
